# POST user and password to http using Retrofit2

Tags: android, post, retrofit2

Need a little bit of help on using Retrofit2 for POST. 
The link post should be like: http://10.100.1.80:40000/login/john/mypass as simple as it looks I can't seem to figure this out. (for now I'm getting SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /10.100.1.80 (port 40000) after 10000ms , in Postman works)

Interface is like:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("login")
 Call<ResponseBody> insertUser(
        @Field("user") String user,
        @Field("password") String password);
```

Main code:

```
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://10.100.1.80:40000/")
            .build();


    APIServicePOST service = retrofit.create(APIServicePOST.class);

    // executes the request
    retrofit2.Call<ResponseBody> call = service.insertUser("john",  "mypass" );
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {


        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            mResponseTv.setText( "OK" +  response.toString() );
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            mResponseTv.setText( t.toString() );
        }
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**
After I fried my brain over a simple POST that didn't worked found out today that I must be on another WI-FI connection on which the IP works.

Comment: instantly you get this error or  after some time?

Comment: @niveshshastri after 10 seconds

Comment: find my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The End-Point should be

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("password")
 Call<ResponseBody> insertUser(
        @Field("user") String user,
        @Field("password") String password);
```

and base URL should be

```
http://10.100.1.80:40000/login/user/
```

Answer (score 0):

When your server is not responding at certain timeout period, it will throw SocketTimeoutException.
Try add more time to fetch the content.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
```

I think you have to add `.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())`
 in your retrofit client.

Like this:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://10.100.1.80:40000/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(client)
        .build();
```

Comment: added the client, still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Define OkHttpClient like this for retrofit object;

```
 OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .readTimeout(240, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .connectTimeout(180,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

And put OkHttpClient object in retrofit object like below:

```
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();
```

Comment: With this 'client it doesn't seem to get the callback after the request.

Answer (score 0):

Sending Data totally depends how your API receives data.

Try following code :

```
@POST("login")
Call<ResponseBody> insertUser(@Body JsonObject jsonData);

JsonObject objJson=new JsonObject();
objJson.add("user",userName);
objJson.add("password",password);
```